# Shape with selector as color doesn't works

Tags: android, android-selector, android-shape

I want to create a shape with selector as solid color.

On Android 5.0+, this code works perfectly, but on 4.X, it doesn't works.

**shape.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/my_selector"/>

    <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**my_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:color="@color/color_1"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

    <item
        android:color="@color/color_2"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

This drawable is applied to `CheckBox` background.

Comment: It looks like it is not supported on older versions of Android. If you want to support them you will need to create diffrent shape drawables for each satate.

Comment: Color state lists in drawables are only supported on devices running API 21+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should change order to write state like this and use your shape in item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_checked="true">
       <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
          <solid android:color="@color/my_selector"/>

         <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp"/>

         <corners android:radius="10dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
          <solid android:color="@color/my_deselec"/>

         <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp"/>

         <corners android:radius="10dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use in this manner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
 <shape>.......</shape> 
</item>
```